# Usage of arithmetic operations on bool values True and False

Tags: python

In python, there is such a feature - True and False can be added, subtracted, etc

Are there any examples where this can be useful?

Is there any real benefit from this feature, for example, when:

- it increases productivity
- it makes the code more concise (without losing speed)
  etc

Comment: This seems like a broad question, but yeah, It's pretty useful at times.

Comment: `valid_elements = sum(is_valid(element) for element in iterable)`

Comment: @Dillon what about using .count(True) instead of sum in this case? Either I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: You could, but that means you'd have to make it into a list to use `.count()`. This of course imposes a linear space complexity on something that may have even been constant (if it were a generator or something), but is doable.

Comment: Another example would be list or string concatenation. `str1 + str2 * include_str2`

Comment: It's worth noting that `bool` is actually a subclass of `int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in most cases it would just be confusing and completely unwarranted to (ab)use this functionality, I'd argue that there are a few cases that are exceptions.

One example would be counting. `True` casts to `1`, so you can count the number of elements that pass some criteria in this fashion, while remaining concise and readable. An example of this would be:

```
valid_elements = sum(is_valid(element) for element in iterable)
```

As mentioned in the comments, this could be accomplished via:

```
valid_elements = list(map(is_valid, iterable)).count(True)
```

but to use `.count(...)`, the object must be a list, which imposes a linear space complexity (iterable may have been a constant space generator for all we know).

Another case where this functionality *might* be usable is as a play on the ternary operator for sequences, where you either want the sequence or an empty sequence depending on the value. Say you want to return the resulting list if a condition holds, otherwise an empty list:

```
return result_list * return_empty
```

or if you are doing a conditional string concatentation

```
result = str1 + str2 * do_concatenate
```

of course, both of these could be solved by using python's ternary operator:

```
return [] if return_empty else result_list
...
result = str1 + str2 if do_concatenate else str1
```

The point being, this behavior does provide other options in a few scenarios that isn't all too unreasonable. Its just a matter of using your best judgement as to whether it'll cause confusion for future readers (yourself included).

Comment: Could you pls elaborate on your point about imposing a linear space complexity?

Comment: @fountainhead in order to use `.count()`, the iterable must be made into a list, which means that it must be stored entirely in memory *at once*. However, what if iterable was `range(1000000)`. Range only takes constant space, generating the next element as its requested. By transforming this into a list, suddenly we need `O(n)` space to store it.

Comment: In this thread, we're discussing something that has or generates bool values, so, `range(1000000)` is perhaps a bad example to illustrate your point. But yes, it could be a generator function that generates 1000000 bool values, of which we are interested in counting the `True`s. I don't see any documentation that says `sum` won't do dumb things like assembling all the elements and then summing them up. But yeah, I guess it's a safe assumption to make.

Comment: @fountainhead my bad, I should have explicitly stated that I mean if the iterable *from the first example* was `range(...)` (where elements are then passed to `is_valid(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid it at all cost. It is confusing and goes against typing. Python being permissive does not mean you should do it ...

Comment: There are exceptions to every rule. blanket statements like these should be said very carefully. I do not agree with this statement when it comes to bools in python, as is, i have definitely used them in niche cases before without losing out on readibility.

Comment: @CedricDruck: I'm not sue about "going against typing", given the rather interesting but little known fact that `bool` is actually a subclass of `int`